# MPVolumeView iPad popover direction

Tags: ios, airplay, mpvolumeview

I’m using an `MPVolumeView` to pop up available AirPlay devices, and the AirPlay button happens to be in the far lower-right corner of my UI. When I tap it, the AirPlay popover that appears is really, really short (like enough for the title and one cell).

I’m wondering if there’s a way I can specify the size of that popover, or the direction from which it appears? I’ve noticed that even the standard iPad popover is tiny, so it’s a system-wide issue, but I’m wondering if I can overcome it. Here’s how this looks on 8.0.2, way too short.

Any ideas?

[image]